# find command doesn't work

Tags: linux, bash, find

I'm trying to find and copy files using find, but using parameter from file.

```
#!/bin/bash

function copyFiles(){
    echo "find $1 -name $2 -exec cp "{}" $3 \;"
    find $1 -name $2
    find $1 -name $2 -exec cp "{}" $3 \;
}


FILECONFIG="/home/backupScript/pathConfig.txt"
DIRDATE=$(date '+%Y-%m-%d');
DIRSCRIPTS="/home/backupScript/"

while IFS='' read -r line || [[ -n "$line" ]]; do
        #echo "Text read from file: $line"
    set -- "$line"
    IFS=","; declare -a ELEMENT=($*)

    DAT1="${ELEMENT[0]}"
    DAT2=""${ELEMENT[1]}""
    DAT3="${ELEMENT[2]}"
    PATHTO=${ELEMENT[2]}/$DIRDATE/
    if [ ! -d $PATHTO ]; then
        mkdir $PATHTO;
    fi
    echo "$DAT2"
    copyFiles $DAT1 $DAT2 $DAT3
    find $DAT1 -name "$DAT2" -exec cp "{}" $DAT3 \;


done < "$FILECONFIG"



FILECONFIG="/home/backupScript/pathConfig.txt"
DIRDATE=$(date '+%Y-%m-%d');
DIRSCRIPTS="/home/backupScript/"

while IFS='' read -r line || [[ -n "$line" ]]; do
        #echo "Text read from file: $line"
    set -- "$line"
    IFS=","; declare -a ELEMENT=($*)

    DAT1="${ELEMENT[0]}"
    DAT2=""${ELEMENT[1]}""
    DAT3="${ELEMENT[2]}"
    PATHTO=${ELEMENT[2]}/$DIRDATE/
    if [ ! -d $PATHTO ]; then
        mkdir $PATHTO;
    fi
    echo "$DAT2"
    copyFiles $DAT1 $DAT2 $DAT3
    find $DAT1 -name "$DAT2" -exec cp "{}" $DAT3 \;


done < "$FILECONFIG"
```

and the only line in my file pathConfig.txt is:

/root/test/,'*.txt',/home/bucket/backupDev/test

When I run it. It does work but trying 
find /root/test/ -name '*.txt' -exec cp {} /home/bucket/backupDev/test \; than is an output in my script.
In terminal It's work the last line.

Comment: If you have a question about `find`, why do you need more than a single line of code (that simply calls `find`)? See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and http://sscce.org/ for guidance on building minimal reproducers.

Comment: `find command doesn't work` is not a proper subject for a question. As long as you can't *prove* that it is not working as described by it's manual, let's assume that it works but your are using it the wrong way.

Comment: ...and there's a *lot* wrong with this code. I'd suggest running it through http://shellcheck.net/ and reading http://mywiki.wooledge.org/UsingFind. Also, you might consider keeping in mind that the only character that can safely be used to delimit UNIX pathnames in a stream are NULs, as any other character -- including both commas and newlines -- can be present *inside* a filename.

Comment: Why do you double up the doublequotes in the `DAT2` assignment? Why don't you just use `WHILE IFS=, read -r DAT1 DAT2 DAT3`?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the quotes around `'*.txt'` in the `pathConfig` file. This will make the `find` command only match names that begin and end with a `'` character. Quotes aren't processed after expanding variables, they're inserted literally into the command line.

So change the line in the file to:

```
/root/test/,*.txt,/home/bucket/backupDev/test
```

You should quote the variables when you use them, though.

```
#!/bin/bash

function copyFiles(){
    echo "find $1 -name $2 -exec cp "{}" $3 \;"
    find "$1" -name "$2" -print -exec cp "{}" "$3" \;
}


FILECONFIG="/home/backupScript/pathConfig.txt"
DIRDATE=$(date '+%Y-%m-%d');
DIRSCRIPTS="/home/backupScript/"

while IFS='' read -r line || [[ -n "$line" ]]; do
        #echo "Text read from file: $line"
    set -- "$line"
    IFS=","; declare -a ELEMENT=($*)

    DAT1="${ELEMENT[0]}"
    DAT2="${ELEMENT[1]}"
    DAT3="${ELEMENT[2]}"
    PATHTO=${ELEMENT[2]}/$DIRDATE/
    if [ ! -d "$PATHTO" ]; then
        mkdir "$PATHTO";
    fi
    echo "$DAT2"
    copyFiles "$DAT1" "$DAT2" "$DAT3"
    find "$DAT1" -name "$DAT2" -exec cp "{}" "$DAT3" \;


done < "$FILECONFIG"
```